# Split string into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following string to split into two columns:

Given:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Mak^1,Jak^2,Smith^3,Lee^4,Joseph^5'
```

I want to split it into two columns:

```
column1  column2
-----------------
Mak      1
Jak      2
Smith    3
Lee      4
Joseph   5
```

My try:

Table-valued Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Split]
(
@InputString VARCHAR(8000), 
@Delimiter VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS @Items TABLE (ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1), Item VARCHAR(8000))

AS
BEGIN
      IF @Delimiter = ' '
      BEGIN
            SET @Delimiter = ','
            SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
      END
      IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
            SET @Delimiter = ','

      DECLARE @Item VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @ItemList VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @DelimIndex INT

      SET @ItemList = @InputString
      SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)

            SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
            SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      END -- End WHILE

      IF @Item IS NOT NULL 
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = @ItemList
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)
      END

      ELSE INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString)

      RETURN

END
```

Function calling:

```
SELECT Item FROM [dbo].[udf_Split](@String ,',');
```

Output:

```
Item
--------------
Mak^1
Jak^2
Smith^3
Lee^4
Joseph^5
```

Comment: Probably `SELECT LEFT(Item, CHARINDEX('^', Item) - 1) AS Column1, RIGHT(Item, LEN(Item) - CHARINDEX('^', Item)) AS Column2 FROM [dbo].[udf_Split](@String ,',')` will be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, Please note that SQL Server 2008 r2 is out of extended support. It's high time to upgrade to a newer version.

For a single string, I would probably use a little dynamic SQL magic trick:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Mak^1,Jak^2,Smith^3,Lee^4,Joseph^5'

DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT Name,Id FROM (VALUES (''' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@String,'''',''''''), ',', '),('''), '^', ''',') + ')) V(Name, Id)';

-- @Sql now contains this:
-- SELECT Name,Id FROM (VALUES ('Mak',1),('Jak',2),('Smith',3),('Lee',4),('Joseph',5)) V(Name, Id)

EXEC(@Sql)
```

Results:

```
Name    Id
Mak     1
Jak     2
Smith   3
Lee     4
Joseph  5
```

Comment: That's actually a really interesting, and different, way to approach this.

Comment: I recommend using `REPLACE(@String,'''','''''')` though; as otherwise this is open to injection (as we don't know where the value of `@String` is coming from).

Answer (score 4):

In the most recent versions of SQL Server, you can use `string_split()`:

```
select left(s.value, charindex('^', value) - 1) as column1,
       stuff(s.value, 1, charindex('^', value), '') as column2
from string_split(@string, ',') s ;
```

You might find it most convenient to download a split function to handle this.

Otherwise, I think a recursive CTE is a simple enough approach:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), null) as row,
             @string as str
      union all
      select convert(varchar(max), left(str, charindex(',', str + ',') - 1)),
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(str, 1, charindex(',', str + ','), ''))
      from cte
      where str <> '' 
     )
select left(cte.row, charindex('^', cte.row) - 1) as column1,
       stuff(cte.row, 1, charindex('^', cte.row), '')
from cte
where row is not null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a7316f99f2a3caaaca49a8275ff3b8dd) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Script below

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Mak^1,Jak^2,Smith^3,Lee^4,Joseph^5';

DECLARE @TempTable AS TABLE(data VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @TempTable
SELECT @String

;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT Split.A.value('.','nvarchar(1000)') AS data
FROM 
(
SELECT CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(data,',','</S><S>')+'</S>' AS XML ) AS data
FROM @TempTable
)AS A
CROSS APPLY data.nodes('S') AS Split(A)
)
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(data,0,CHARINDEX('^',data)))) AS column1,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(data,CHARINDEX('^',data)+1,LEN (data)))) AS column2
FROM CTE
```

Result

```
column1 column2
-------------------
Mak         1
Jak         2
Smith       3
Lee         4
Joseph      5
```

Use the above script create table valued parameter function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_SplitFun](@InputData VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @Return TABLE ( column1 VARCHAR(200),column2 INT)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @TempTable AS TABLE
(
data VARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO @TempTable
SELECT @InputData

;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT Split.A.value('.','nvarchar(1000)') AS data
FROM 
(
SELECT CAST('<S>'+REPLACE(data,',','</S><S>')+'</S>' AS XML ) AS data
FROM @TempTable
)AS A
CROSS APPLY data.nodes('S') AS Split(A)
)
INSERT INTO @Return(column1,column2)
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(data,0,CHARINDEX('^',data)))) AS column1,
       LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(data,CHARINDEX('^',data)+1,LEN (data)))) AS column2
FROM CTE

RETURN;

END
```

Execute the Function like below

```
DECLARE @InputData VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Mak^1,Jak^2,Smith^3,Lee^4,Joseph^5';

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[udf_SplitFun] (@InputData)
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel a much better approach to this would be to get rid of that awful `WHILE` and use a set based approach; we'll be using [`delimitedsplit8K`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function) here (if you are on 2012+ use [`delimitedsplit8k_lead`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) or on 2016+ you can `STRING_SPLIT`).

With that in mind, the above becomes quite trivial:

```
DECLARE @String varchar(MAX) = 'Mak^1,Jak^2,Smith^3,Lee^4,Joseph^5';

SELECT LEFT(DS.Item,CHARINDEX('^',DS.Item)-1) AS Col1,
       STUFF(DS.Item,1, CHARINDEX('^',DS.Item),'') AS Col2
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@String, ',') DS;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use that split function another time to split each line by caret. Like:

```
SELECT SplitByCaret1.Item, SplitByCaret2.Item 
FROM [dbo].[udf_Split](@String ,',') SplitByComma
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[udf_Split](SplitByComma.Item ,'^') Splitted WHERE Splitted.ID=1) SplitByCaret1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[udf_Split](SplitByComma.Item ,'^') Splitted WHERE Splitted.ID=2) SplitByCaret2
```